# Basic 3D voxel grid in Mayavi

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, vtk, mayavi

I'm trying to visualize a 3D array through Mayavi in Python.  I simply want to create a structured 3D voxel grid in which I can show some pre-specified voxel-space-filling points.  I do not think that I want

The only example that I can find that I think is relatively relevant is [this MRI example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mri.html#example-mri).  I can use the following code to get a somewhat workable example:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

data = (100, 100, 100)
data = np.zeros(data)
data[0:50, 50:70, 0:50] = 1
data[0:50, 0:20, 0:50] = 1

src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data)
outer = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src)

mlab.show()
```

This is able to generate the following images:
[image]
[image]
As you can see, not all sides of the boxes are generated, even though those points have the same value as the sides of the boxes that are generated.

Is there a way to visualize every single point in the numpy array that has value equal to 1?  I am fine if there is no iso-surface visualization -- in fact, I would prefer some Minecraft-esque blocky voxel visualization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hi**

```
import mayavi.mlab
import numpy

data = (100, 100, 100)
data = numpy.zeros(data)
data[0:50, 50:70, 0:50] = 1
data[0:50, 0:20, 0:50] = 1

xx, yy, zz = numpy.where(data == 1)

mayavi.mlab.points3d(xx, yy, zz,
                     mode="cube",
                     color=(0, 1, 0),
                     scale_factor=1)

mayavi.mlab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a way to individually color the voxels?

Comment: As far I know, you can try to use a custom color map. Or you still can plot each voxel group iteratively with a different color.

Comment: Nice, but very slow to interact with.

Comment: @martinako its actually very fast to interact with, even with millions of data samples; are you using up to date qt?